# Mapping software/website with tunnel layer

Tags: maps

In sites like Google Maps you can see roads and highways and get an idea of possible paths. But the tunnels in cities, which are roads anyway, can't be seen at least in the default view.

Is there a mapping software, either desktop or web-based which shows tunnels (in the default view or maybe in a layer)?

Comment: If desktop, what OS? How much are you willing to spend, or must it be free-of-charge?

Comment: I'll be installing any OS or buying a commercial product if I can use that feature ;)